# OperationalError : "no such column" when using ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django

so I'm trying to make a user-specific page with Django.
In my models.py file, I have this code:

```
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="todolist", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But I keep getting this "no such column: main_todolist.user_id" error. 
I'm aware that when using ForeignKey, Django automatically creates a column named '..._id' as I do the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command.  
I've also tried deleting all the migrations and pycache files except '**init**.py', but nothing works.

I would very much appreciate your help. :) 
*The version of my Django is 3.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically creates a column named `..._id` in **DATABASE** but in your code you still have to use `user` instead of `user_id` since you named your field like this `user = models.ForeignKey(...)`

Try again with `main_todolist.user`

Comment: You mean the variable ```user``` ?

Comment: Adding _id to a foreign key attribute of a model instance gets you the id of the user. So in Ryan case, it should work.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou `.id` should have worked but not `_id`

Comment: @Ibris It should. To check this: just open a shell on any django project you have with the auth app activated and type 'Permission.objects.first().content_type_id'.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Indeed it does. If you can find the reason of it I'm interested in it. Just to know why.

Comment: @Ibris Don't really know if this is the original reason, but checking if model_instance.fk_attribute_id is None allows to check if an object is linked or not without triggering a database request.